# nGram frequency using Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

So I have some items in MongoDB with a field named `title` (and many others) but we'll focus on this one.

I want to retrieve the most used words overall time, for example, the expected result would be

```
{
  "christmas 2017": 30,
  "foo bar": 4,
  "apple iphone": 10,
  ...
}
```

So I can then render a bar plot and see things, with my code I can 'do this'  but it also gives me ngrams with just 1 frequency, which I don't want, because they're not used more than once, so useless info.

The point of this, is to get the most common words within titles, I think a good ngram range would be 2-3 words, because 1 is not enough and more than 3 is too specific.

This is my code, which is working but I need a way to get ride of the non repeated things (and maybe also a better way to achieve this)

```
vector = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
n_gram = vectorizer.fit_transform(df[text_field])
frequencies = n_gram.toarray().sum(axis=0)
results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
results.plot.bar()
```

Needless to say that the drawn bar, has a huge amount of irrelevant info (things with just 1 frequency)

And this code, I'll be using it to parse long text fields, such as `description`, so I need to get a clean list of the most used things.

As a bonus, if I could just tell the script the minimum repeating frequency, that'll be awesome, so it can fit any need in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps after you have got nGrams.

```
nG=["apple iphone","apple iphone","apple iphone",
    "apple iphone", "christmas 2017","christmas 2017",
    "apple iphone","apple iphone", "foo bar",
    "christmas 2017","christmas 2017","christmas 2017",
    "christmas 2017","apple iphone"]

from collections import Counter
import heapq
nG=Counter(nG)
ng
```

Output:

`Counter({'apple iphone': 7, 'christmas 2017': 6, 'foo bar': 1})`

Another Command:

`heapq.nlargest(5,nG,key=nG.get)`

Output:

`['apple iphone', 'christmas 2017', 'foo bar']`

Comment: Nice answer, but how can I, like in my original script, output a list of the nGrams > x with the count in the dict `{"apple iphone": 7}` instead `["apple iphone"]` because the wanted result is a plot with those infos